# Why are items in a flex container not reordered when adding a new item?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have two flex containers containing flex items, each with an order property. Each flex item has an event listener. When clicking on a flex item (a div in this case) the div moves to the other flex container.

But if I for instance click on the div with order 1 below, the new position will be to the right of the div with order 3 in the container with id #non-selected. So in some way the flex container is not updated. Do I do something wrong or is this the expected behaviour? I run Version 91.4.0esr, Firefox for openSUSE Leap, openSUSE-15.2 and Google Chrome Version 98.0.4758.80 (Official Build) (64-bit).

```js
function moveOption() {

  let optionDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

  optionDivs.forEach(function(div) {
    div.addEventListener('click', function() {
      if (this.parentElement.id === 'non-selected') {
        document.getElementById('selected').append(div);
      } else {
        document.getElementById('non-selected').append(div);
      }
    });
  });
}

moveOption();
```

```css
#selected,
#non-selected {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
  gap: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 50px;
  max-height: 100px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  cursor: grab;
  width: max-content;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="module" src="bc-select.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  Click or Order 1 &quot;button&quot; and it will be positioned right to the Order 3 &quot;button&quot; despite it has a lower value for the order property.
  <div id="selected">
    <div order="1" class="item">Order 1</div>
    <div order="2" class="item">Order 2</div>
  </div>

  <div id="non-selected">
    <div order="3" class="item">Order 3</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: I will fix that tomorrow:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non-standard `order` attribute does not affect ordering within a Flex or Grid container. You need to set [the `order` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) instead.

So instead of:

```
<div order="1">
```

you need:

```
<div style="order:1;">
```

Updated demo:

```js
function moveOption() {

  let optionDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

  optionDivs.forEach(function(div) {
    div.addEventListener('click', function() {
      if (this.parentElement.id === 'non-selected') {
        document.getElementById('selected').append(div);
      } else {
        document.getElementById('non-selected').append(div);
      }
    });
  });
}

moveOption();
```

```css
#selected,
#non-selected {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
  gap: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 50px;
  max-height: 100px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  cursor: grab;
  width: max-content;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="selected">
  <div style="order:1;" class="item">Order 1</div>
  <div style="order:2;" class="item">Order 2</div>
</div>

<div id="non-selected">
  <div style="order:3;" class="item">Order 3</div>
</div>
```